# How to set value of an attribute as value of 'Maximum Rate' property in Control rate processor in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, druid

I have a flow where I am using control rate processor to control the data flow, I will submit tasks in druid using those files, for example let's say I have a total of 10 files. I will first ask my control rate processor to send 2 flow files to downstream, now I will submit those files as tasks in druid and fetch their status, if 1 task is running and another one is success I need to ask my control rate processor to send only 1 file, if 2 tasks are running dont submit tasks until they are completed, if 2 are success then send 2 files from control rate.I an counting the tasks which are running and adding them to an attribute,so is there a way that control rate processor takes the value of count attribute in **Maximum rate property**. I've checked the **Rate Control Criteria** property which can be set to **Attribute Value** but I am confused how to set the rate to attribute value.